# How to make Android WebView open above keyboard for user's visibility?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I am opening a web view on Android, that takes user to enter email and password, once user clicks on any entry field, keyboard covers the fields entirely, and there is no scrolling feature enabled on the web page, so user is unable to see the entry fields, I want to give some room for the user to see the entry fields while taking input.

adding this property in activity in manifest file did not resolve my issue
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

How can I solve this problem, I tried adding the Web View inside a Scroll View, but that is not working, is there any way for the web view to open above keyboard so as for the user to see what is being typed